# UPDATE same table with LIKE

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

I have a product table with 30,000 products in it.

```
SELECT product_id,sku PRODUCT T1

1  3518
12 3518[2]
11 88322[2]
10 915703[12]
 9 915703
```

product_id's 1 and 12 are the same product but in variation, so I want to update product_description.tag both values.

```
product_id = 1
product_description.tag = 3518, 3518[2]

product_id = 12
product_description.tag = 3518, 3518[2]

product_id = 11
product_description.tag = 88322[2]

product_id = 10
product_description.tag = 915703[12],915703

product_id = 9
product_description.tag = 915703[12],915703
```

Think that makes sense, I just cannot get my head around doing a LIKE '%3518' on the same table and updating another.

Can you help?

Thanks

Stu

Comment: I take it `product_description` is a different table? If so, how does it link to your `product` table?

Comment: Two tables.
product and product_description both with corresponding product_id fields.

Answer (score 0):

That is a horrid schema, take this moment to partially fix it by create a new table say `Product_Masters` and populate it with the result from:

```
SELECT product_id, 
    (
    SELECT MIN(product_id)
    FROM PRODUCT T2 
    WHERE T2.sku LIKE T1.sku + '%'
    ) AS master_project_id
FROM PRODUCT T1
```

Then use this as your list for setting the product_description field. first update the description for the record corresponding to master_product_id and then update all the sub-projects to match that value.

Comment: It is OpenCart.  Thats smart using the MIN(, I like your thinking.  I will give that a shot.  Thank you for your help.  Stu